TDML: Error occured while writing to garbage collector file
I was facing the error above in teradataml py package on Win11, when using Dataframe.from_query().
But I am sure the exception would be triggered in (many) other methods.
Why ?
Because of a generic bug in garbagecollector.py constructor, namely the filename of the GarbageCollector contains one or multiple : chars, which is invalid in Windows.
Note this is teradataml v20.0.0.3
No issue if run in linux/WSL.

To avoid closure of this question, it may make sense to rewrite the title to state the problem you faced (the technical problem, not your inability to access support when you lack a license), reframe the question to spell out exactly what you did and the issue you ran into, and then answer your own question by posting an answer and adding enough details to to help future searchers.

u are absolutely right - wrote initial message out of frustration. Wished TD was using GitHub more than just a shell for their SDKs

Until fixed, try to use pandas or SQLAlchemy equivalent functionality.
For my use case, pd.read_sql() did the trick.
